# Custom React/MUI UI Library breaking React app when imported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, package, esbuild

I'm currently trying to write a UI library using React and Material-UI to use across all my projects, if I write custom React components example:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = (() => {
    return(
        <>
            <h1>Hello React</h1>
            <p>This is an example export of multiple components</p>
        </>
    )
})
```

Then I build the library and import it to my main app (Ruby on Rails/React). I can import and use this component that I've created within my UI library, use them, and see them appear on my webpage without issue. Issues arise when I start using components that include things from the @mui/materials library.

Example, I've extended our previous component to be something like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography/Typography';

export const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = (() => {
    return(
        <>
            <h1>Hello React</h1>
            <p>This is an example export of multiple components</p>
            <Typography variant={'h1'}>HELLO MUI</Typography>
        </>
    )
})
```

Build and import this modified library into the main app, from there I can import the component into my react entry point without issue. When I launch the webserver nothing appears on the webpage, upon opening the console I see these errors:

[image]

I've noticed that deleting the `app (Rails) > node_modules > ui > node_modules` folder resolves then issue and the components then get rendered. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue permanently, since I don't want to have to contiuously have to go in and delete the installed node_modules from my library everytime I upgrade/install it.

Heres the `package.json` and `esbuild.js` files from my UI library:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "UI Library",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "author": "Jebs",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node esbuild.js && tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.0",
    "esbuild-node-externals": "^1.8.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.4"
  }
}
```

`esbuild.js` file:

```
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require('esbuild-node-externals');
esbuild
  .build({
    entryPoints: ['./src/index.tsx'],
    outfile: 'dist/index.js',
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    treeShaking: true,
    platform: 'node',
    format: 'cjs',
    target: 'node14',
    plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()],
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

and `package.json` from my rails app:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.2",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "ui": "../../ui"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks ahead of time

I tried several different esbuild configurations, I've tried to modify my projects dependencies in different ways to avoid the unnecessary installations

Comment: Where is the useContext call coming from?

Comment: Jeremie Bourgeois do you get solution for this? I am having same issue with same use case.